# css how to break line when long data

Tags: html, css

I have search many of here but still not solve my problem, I have problem with my data is dynamic, some long and some short, short is never mind but for long text, I want it's beak line. but it's no break and draw the same line line(make duplicate text). please help me, this this my HTML

```
Company name: <a id="com_name">REGIONAL COMMUNITY FORESTRY TRAINING CENTER FOR ASIA AND PACIFIC (RECOFTC)</a>
```

and my CSS:

```
#com_name{
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal
}
```

but my result like this [image]

What I want

```
Company name: REGIONAL COMMUNITY FORESTRY TRAINING CENTER FOR ASIA AND 
              PACIFIC (RECOFTC)
```

Comment: use line-height:28px;

Comment: yes my problem solve by add `line-height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `line-height` in your CSS.

```
#com_name{
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**using** `line-height: 2;` **or** `line-height: 20px;`

**Example - 1: using `line-height: 2;`**

```
#com_name{
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: 2; 
}
```

```css
#com_name{
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
Company name: <a id="com_name">REGIONAL COMMUNITY FORESTRY TRAINING CENTER FOR ASIA AND PACIFIC (RECOFTC) </a>
```

**Example- 2: using `line-height: 20px;`**

```
#com_name{
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: 20px; 
}
```

```css
#com_name{
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
Company name: <a id="com_name">REGIONAL COMMUNITY FORESTRY TRAINING CENTER FOR ASIA AND PACIFIC (RECOFTC) </a>
```

Comment: it's help me by used `line-height`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
.class_name {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
#com_name{
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: normal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this problem.You can use `word-wrap`,See my following example.

[image: Like this you will get]

```css
#dob{
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block !important;*/
 vertical-align: middle !important;*/
 color: #365899; 
    cursor: pointer;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 158px;
}
```

```html
<div id="selectDob">
<select label="Day" name="birthdat_day" class="days" id="selectDateOfBirth">
<option value="0" selected="1">Day</option>
</select>
<select label="Month" name="birthday_month" class="months" id="selectDateOfBirth">
<option value="0" selected="1">Month</option>
</select>
<select label="Year" name="birthday_year" class="years" id="selectDateOfBirth">
<option value="0" selected="1">Year</option> 
</select>
<div id="dobContent">
   <a href="#" id="dob"  data-toggle="popover">Why do I need to provide my date of birth?</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    /*anchor tag*/
    #com_name{
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 50%;
      white-space: normal
    }

    /*set width for first p tag*/
    .first{
        width:8%;
    }

    /*set width, margin-top and margin-left for second p tag*/
    .second{
        margin-left:8%;
        margin-top:-33px;
        width:32%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p class="first">Company name:</p>
    <p class="second"> <a id="com_name">REGIONAL COMMUNITY FORESTRY TRAINING CENTER FOR ASIA 
AND PACIFIC (RECOFTC)</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful